# Save and lock entity with Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, concurrency

I'm looking for a way to save and immediately lock an entity on a DB in order to avoid that other thread access the entity before the thread creator ends. 
I'm using Hibernate 4.3.11 and Spring 4.2.5. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Although there is lock mode -  [LockMode.WRITE](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/) - but as the documentation states

> A WRITE lock is obtained when an object is updated or inserted. This
>   lock mode is for internal use only and is not a valid mode for load()
>   or lock() (both of which throw exceptions if WRITE is specified)..

If it's just that you are only inserting rows then you cannot specifically lock the **database rows** using hibernate as the rows are not yet committed. 
The moment your code (hibernate or without) inserts rows in database and not yet commits - there are transactional locks held which gets released on transaction commit. The nature of locks and the manner in which this internally happens is database specific. However if you are interested in locking some rows (already existing) , then you 
can query the data using

```
session.get(TestEntity.class, 1, LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```

This will hold a pessimistic lock (typically by issuing SELECT .... FOR UPDATE) for the duration of transaction and no other thread/transaction can modify the data on which lock has been taken.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way should be increase transaction level to serializable. 
This level ensure data is locked until is not used in other transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this way the entire table will be locked. I want lock only the new entity.

Comment: the more higher the isolation level, the lower the performance its going to be.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate offer's two types of locks Optimistic and Pessimistic. Its straight forward.

1)Optimistic uses versioning where in it will have a version column in the database and check it before it updates or else throw the exception

2)Pessimistic is some thing like a database handles the locking on that row and it will get released after the operation is completed, there are few options are there which is similarly like how you imagine like read lock, write lock

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html

Comment: I want to know that after getting response also I did not want to release the lock for next 10 minutes (Some business requirement) Will it be possible by any way using this perssimistic locking?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PostgreSQL I think the below example works:

```java
    @Query(value = """with ins_artist as (
                          insert into artist
                          values (301, 'Whoever1')
                          returning *
                      ) select artist_id
                      from ins_artist
                      for update""", nativeQuery = true)
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    Long insertArtist(); // returns artist ID
```

PS: I ran this query on https://postgres.devmountain.com/ . But it would need testing on a Java app.